# Mongo/Mongoose Date Search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs, moment-timezone

If I run this query with no date filter like below - you can see there is a result with a 'timestamp' entry as expected:-

**Query with no date filter**

```
Activity.find().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

**Output:-**

```
[
  {
    _id: 6305554bd407d9912b99726e,
    timestamp: 2022-08-23T20:00:00.000Z,
    player1Name: 'Bob',
    player1Token: '5106f70c68a639112c08254cbc96b9ea67e154c1',
    action: 'added some OOC notes about',
    player2Name: 'Derek',
    player2Token: 'c30fa3cee94828f0f1296abf717aedc353420555'
  }
]
```

So, I'm not understanding why *this* query would yield no results.

**Query with date filter**

```
console.log(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).startOf('day').utc().toDate());
console.log(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).endOf('day').utc().toDate());

Activity.find({
        'timestamp' : {
           '$gte': momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).startOf('day').utc().toDate(),
           '$lt': momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).endOf('day').utc().toDate()
        }
  }).then(result => {

  console.log(result);
});
```

**Output:-**

```
2022-08-23T07:00:00.000Z
2022-08-24T06:59:59.999Z
[]
```

You can see the date of the timestamp in the first result is greater than 2022-08-23T07:00:00.000Z (and less than 2022-08-24T06:59:59.999Z), so why would this possibly yeild no results?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe the timestamp is stored as a string in mongodb

Comment: @CharchitKapoor,  you are right! I entered this entry manually via Mongo Compass and wasn't paying attention. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).startOf('day').utc().toDate());
console.log(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).endOf('day').utc().toDate());

Activity.find({
    'timestamp': {
        '$gt':ISODate(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).startOf('day').utc().toDate()),
        '$lt':ISODate(momentTimezone().tz(timezonePref).endOf('day').utc().toDate())
    }
}).then(result => {

    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I did try that with no joy (in that ISODate() only works in Compass, and not Node. I imagine I could import it but it looks like CharchitKapoor's comment fixed it).